# How do I access nested structures to and access their contents to be used?

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to learn how to use nested structures and am doing a "pthread producer and consumer" like example.

I have these initialized:

```
int MAILBOX_SIZE = 10;

typedef struct Message {
        int bytes;
        void *data;
} Message;

typedef struct Mailbox {
        Message *queue;
        int in; //place to add next element in buffer
        int out; //place to remove next element in buffer
        int cnt; //number of elements in buffer
} Mailbox;

void mb_init(Mailbox *sb, int size);
```

Now I want to create this initialization function to be able to access the queue.

My approach for it may be wrong, but what I was thinking was this:

```
void mb_init(Mailbox *sb, int size){
        sb->queue=(Message*)malloc(sizeof(Message));
        sb->queue->bytes = size;
        printf("%i\n", sb->queue->bytes);

}

int mb_put(Mailbox *sb, Message *msg){
        //actions of the producer

}

int mb_get(Mailbox *sb, Message *msg){
        //actions of the consumer
}
```

And my main (pseudo code because I have alot more in main) is this:

```
int main() {
   struct Mailbox *myMailbox;
   mb_init(myMailbox, MAILBOX_SIZE);
}
```

I end up getting a "segmentation fault", and I know it is coming from my "mb_init" function, because I'm not quite sure how to handle nested structures.
How can I set the size of the message from this init function using nested structures?

Any help is appreciated.. I am learning C; I'm sorry if some things aren't the "most efficient" way to be done.

Comment: you have to pass the struct pointer by reference not by value otherwise you have to return `sb` `in mb_init` .

Comment: @hiqutj if you pass by value and doesn't return the pointer to new allocated memory when the function returns from the `stack` the necessary changes are lost too.

Comment: @SeekAddo I end up getting this: expected ‘struct Mailbox *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Mailbox **’ if I add a "&" in front of myMailbox in mb_init(myMailbox, MAILBOX_SIZE);

Comment: You haven't actually allocated a `struct Mailbox` to pass to `mb_init()`... you declared a pointer to one, but didn't point it at anything.

Comment: I still don't think you need to pass a pointer to a pointer. You're not repointing the pointer to struct. The issue is what Dmitri describes.

Comment: Oh wow.. I see what you guys are saying. Thank you so much @Dmitri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already said, your problem is passing by value instead of by reference.

There are so many ways to do this. You can try this one

> in Main

```
Mailbox myMailbox;                 // memory allocated on the stack, life span till the *return*
mb_init(&myMailbox, MAILBOX_SIZE); // pass the address here
// and don't forget to free the queue memory when you are done with it



//Main ends here




/* In your code if you don't return a pointer to the memory allocated here on the heap. 
You will not get those changes when the function return from the stack. 
It is best practice to return a pointer to the allocated heap memory
 before the function returns. */

void mb_init(Mailbox *sb, int size){
        ......
        ......

}
```

Comment: If he wants to use a pointer, like he had in the question, he just needs to `malloc()` (or whatever) the struct before passing it to `mb_init()`.  There's no need for a double pointer.

Comment: That needs some explanation. It makes the caller responsible for allocating the memory. In this example, `myMailbox` is allocated on the stack and will only live as long as the current function. You can't, for example, `return myMailbox`. To do that, it would have to be heap allocated: `Mailbox *myMailbox = malloc(sizeof(Mailbox))`.

Comment: @Schwern myMailbox is allocated on the stack and until the return in the main it still available. The user is only responsible to free the memory in the inner struct.

Comment: @SeekAddo I agree, it's fine in this specific case because it's in `main`. But that's just quick sample code. The OP probably doesn't understand stack memory. If it isn't explained they'll go and use that technique where it's not appropriate and be back wondering why they're getting a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler warnings (`-Wall`) point at the problem.

```
test.c:27:12: warning: variable 'myMailbox' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
   mb_init(myMailbox, MAILBOX_SIZE);
           ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

You're passing in myMailbox and using it without having allocated memory for it. In general, don't pass in a pointer to an initialization function, return one.

You also shouldn't initialize an empty message in the Mailbox, just init the Mailbox. Let whomever is adding the messages initialize the Message and pass it in.

```
Mailbox *mb_init(int size){
        Mailbox *sb = malloc(sizeof(Mailbox));

        sb->queue = NULL;
        sb->in = 0;
        sb->out = 0;
        sb->cnt = 0;

        return sb;
}
```

---

This brings us to our next problem: you only allocated space in your queue for one message. And it's not storing pointers to messages, it will have to copy them and they can get huge.

Instead, use an array of Message pointers.

```
const size_t MAILBOX_SIZE = 10;

typedef struct {
        size_t bytes;
        void *data;
} Message;

typedef struct {
        Message **queue;
        size_t in; //place to add next element in buffer
        size_t out; //place to remove next element in buffer
        size_t cnt; //number of elements in buffer
        size_t max_size;
} Mailbox;

Mailbox *mb_init(size_t size){
        Mailbox *mb = malloc(sizeof(Mailbox));
        mb->queue = malloc(sizeof(Message*) * size);
        mb->in = 0;
        mb->out = 0;
        mb->cnt = 0;
        mb->max_size = size;

        return mb;
}

void mb_destroy( Mailbox *mb ) {
    free(mb->queue);
    free(mb);
}
```

I've made a few other changes. The most obvious is switching to `size_t` to store the size of things. This avoids bumping into the integer limit.

I added a destructor, you should always write an initializer and a destructor for all your structs.

And Mailbox now stores its max size. It'll need to know that to avoid adding too many messages. Later versions of this would switch to a linked list or reallocate the queue as needed.

I've also made sure to always use the `typedef`s, not the underlying struct types, and went so far as to remove the names from the struct so they cannot be referenced directly. Now there's only one way to refer to the struct, which is easier to read. It also provides stronger encapsulation should there be a radical change to the type, like switching to an integer which indexes other storage (not likely, but you never know).

Comment: Thank you for the help! This will definitely allow me to keep on going. I'll use this as a foundation and see if I have any questions :)